# Entity Framework generic recursive saving C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have been asked to create a generic library that will be able to handle saving objects while they are not in trackable state using EF.

This is my object

```
[Table("Address")]
public class Address : Entity
{
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

And `object Get<Country>(false)` indicates that the object is as `AsNoTracking` state

```
var user = new User() { UserName = "Admin" };
user.Adress = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Address>() { new Address() { Name = "Line 3", Country = repository.Get<Country>(false).First() } };
user.Adress.First().Country.Name = "sdsdsd"; // Only update!!!
repository.Save(user);
```

My saving method

```
/// <summary>
/// Update or insert record, this will loop throw all object recursive and find out items state 
/// and do update or insert or delete, depending on item primary key and ItemState (optional to be included in the object)
/// be aware that deleting an object will also result to delete all other objects that are connected to it.
/// be also sure to include all objects that are depending on the current object when you removing an item, or else a dependency exception will be thrown in
/// </summary>
/// <param name="iEntityList"></param>
/// <param name="saveChanges">false if handling commit outside the function</param>
/// <returns></returns>
protected IEntity Save(List<IEntity> iEntityList, bool saveChanges = true, ItemState? overrideState = null, bool isExternalData = false)
{
    if (iEntityList == null || !iEntityList.Any())
        return null;

    if (overrideState != null)
        iEntityList.ForEach(x => x.State = overrideState.Value);

    var db = context.Set(iEntityList.First().GetType());

    foreach (var entry in iEntityList)
    {
        var state = entry.State;

        if (state == ItemState.Removed && entry.ID <= 0) // no need to be included in Transaction. it dose not exist in the db anyway
            continue;

        DbEntityEntry<IEntity> obj = context.Entry(entry);

        if (state == ItemState.Added)
        {
            if (entry.ID > 0 && (obj.State == EntityState.Detached || obj.State == EntityState.Added || isExternalData))
            {
                if (isExternalData)
                    obj.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                var existingItem = db.Find(entry.ID);
                obj = context.Entry(existingItem as IEntity);

                if (isExternalData)
                {
                    obj.State = EntityState.Detached;
                    continue;
                }

                obj.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry);
                obj.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            foreach (var prop in entry.GetType().GetProperties().
                Where(x =>
                (x.GetCustomAttribute<ExecludeFromEntityFramework>(false) == null) &&
                (x.PropertyType.IsGenericList() ||
                (x.PropertyType.IsClass && x.PropertyType != typeof(string)))))
            {
                if (!prop.CanRead || !prop.CanWrite || prop.GetMethod.IsStatic || prop.SetMethod.IsStatic)
                    continue;

                var propValue = entry.GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(entry, null);
                if (propValue != null)
                {
                    List<IEntity> value;

                    if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericList())
                        value = (propValue as System.Collections.IList).Cast<IEntity>().ToList();
                    else value = (propValue as IEntity).Convert(prop.PropertyType).Cast<IEntity>().ToList();

                    if (value != null && value.Any())
                    {
                        if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericList())
                        {
                            if (value.Any(x => x.ID <= 0 && x.State != ItemState.Removed) && prop.GetCustomAttribute<ExternalData>() == null)
                                obj.Entity.GetProperty(prop.Name, value.FindAll(x => x.ID <= 0 && x.State != ItemState.Removed).Convert(propValue.GetType()));
                        }
                        else
                            if (value.First().ID <= 0 && value.First().State != ItemState.Removed && prop.GetCustomAttribute<ExternalData>() == null)
                            obj.Entity.GetProperty(prop.Name, value.First());
                        Save(value, false, null, prop.GetCustomAttribute<ExternalData>() != null);
                    }
                }
            }

            obj.State = entry.ID > 0 ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            if (obj.State == EntityState.Detached || isExternalData)
            {
                if (isExternalData)
                    obj.State = EntityState.Unchanged;

                var existingItem = db.Find(entry.ID);
                obj = context.Entry(existingItem as IEntity);

                if (isExternalData)
                {
                    obj.State = EntityState.Detached;
                    continue;
                }

                obj.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry);
            }

            foreach (var prop in entry.GetType().GetProperties().
            Where(x =>
            (x.GetCustomAttribute<ExecludeFromEntityFramework>(false) == null) &&
            (x.PropertyType.IsGenericList() ||
            (x.PropertyType.IsClass && x.PropertyType != typeof(string)))))
            {
                if (!prop.CanRead || !prop.CanWrite || prop.GetMethod.IsStatic || prop.SetMethod.IsStatic)
                    continue;

                var propValue = entry.GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(entry, null);
                if (propValue != null)
                {
                    List<IEntity> value;
                    if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericList())
                        value = (propValue as System.Collections.IList).Cast<IEntity>().ToList();
                    else value = (propValue as IEntity).Convert(prop.PropertyType).Cast<IEntity>().ToList();

                    Save(value, false, ItemState.Removed, prop.GetCustomAttribute<ExternalData>() != null);

                }

            }
            obj.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
    }

    if (saveChanges)
    {
        this.SaveChanges();
        return iEntityList.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else 
        return iEntityList.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The problem is that Country has the primary key `ID` so it should only be updated but for some reason when i indicate that address is new object Country state changes to new to so I will get new object of type Country in the database.

I only need to have new address and a reference to the country.

If `Country.ID == 0` then mark country as new and add it to the database

Comment: Did you try and debugging it? Your code needs to be refactored. It is hard to follow. And I am not sure why the saving needs to be done recursively. This will cause performance problems. Why recursive?

Comment: Well let's say you have user and user have addresses and addresses have samthing else and so on. How do u save them all and to make sure that all forgen keys are created on the right place without doing it rescurive.  Make in mind that it's not trackable in ef and it have to be generict